# Какова идея решения такой задачи на Си?

Tags: c, массивы

1. Нужно вывести все слова текста, которые начинаются с согласных букв, не используя указатели.
2. Нужно вывести все слова текста, которые имеют окончание, например, "ed". Не используя указатели.  Можно ли обойтись без доп.массивов?

Comment: *"не используя указатели"* -- очередной преподавательский заскок? *" Можно ли обойтись без доп.массивов?"* Можно ли обойтись без доп.массивов?"* - можно. Но сам текст как задаётся хорошо бы знать.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему

Comment: Мне интересно, преподаватель/вопрошающий знает о том, что массив это тот же указатель (если закрыть глаза на синтаксический сахар). Поэтому, при данной формулировке задачу сложно решить.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы знаете, как работать с указателями - то справитесь: просто используйте как указатель индекс в массиве.

Например, идете индексом по строке, как только после пробела встречаете букву - проверяете, согласная ли. Если да - выводите посимвольно, пока индекс не покажет, что слово кончилось...

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот вариант для первого вопроса. Цифры считает согласными, но это мелочи. Только латиница, но это тоже малочи :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* проверить на гласную проще, чем на согласную */
static int is_vowel( char c )
{
    return c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' ||
           c == 'o' || c == 'u' || c == 'y';
}

int main( void )
{
    static char text[] = "city lop engirt nods osapi hurryproof suss ax";
    size_t i = 0;

    while( i < sizeof( text ) ) {
        /* пропускаем всё, что не буква */
        if( !isalnum( text[i] ) ) {
            i++;
            continue;
        }

        if( !is_vowel( text[i] ) ) {
            /* не гласная - выводим слово */
            putchar( text[i] );
            while( ++i < sizeof( text ) && isalnum( text[i] ) ) {
                putchar( text[i] );
            }
            putchar( '\n' );
        }
        else
        {
            /* гласная - пропускаем слово */
            while( i < sizeof(text) && isalnum(text[i]) )
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Второй чуть сложней, но давать сразу решение - неспортивно :)

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на второй вопрос - да запросто. Например:

```
char text[] = "dfgh asdved wdfbjh asvved jhkjklled sbdb";

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0;text[i];i = j)
    {
        while(text[i] && !isalpha(text[i])) ++i;
        if (text[i] == 0) break;
        // Тут i указывает на начало слова
        j = i;
        while(isalpha(text[j])) ++j;
        // j указывает на первый символ за словом
        if (text[j-2] == 'e' && text[j-1] == 'd')
        {
            for(int k = i; k < j; ++k) putc(text[k],stdout);
            puts("");
        }
    }
}
```